# excel offset and hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, offset

In the same cell, is there a way to hyperlink the offset formula? Currently cell B2 has this formula: `=OFFSET(C2,0,MAX((C2:N2<>"")*(COLUMN(C2:N2)))-COLUMN(C2))` [<-- I don't remember where I got this but it works], which extracts the last non-empty value of a row, which is either a filename or a folder name. Now I want B2 to also hyperlink to a drive/folder for example.

In B2, I tried:
`=HYPERLINK("c\users\[name]\documents\"&OFFSET(C2,0,MAX((C2:N2<>"")*(COLUMN(C2:N2)))-COLUMN(C2)),B2)`

which of course doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

found solution. i ended up JOINTEXT-ing the different columns to a cell, from that cell get the last string from [extract test from last from last specific char](https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/formulas/excel-extract-text-after-last-instance-of-character.html)
`=HYPERLINK("c:\users\[name]\documents\folder1\"&RIGHT(O2,LEN(O2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(O2,"\","#",LEN(O2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(O2,"\",""))))),RIGHT(O2,LEN(O2)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(O2,"\","#",LEN(O2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(O2,"\",""))))))`